# Use TFS build server but don't deploy

Tags: azure, tfs, msbuild

I have a build definition set up that successfully builds on each check-in and deploys to the cloud (Azure).  However, I'd like to know how to modify it if I wanted it to build, but not actually deploy to Azure.  Just build after the check-in, make sure nothing breaks, and that's it.  I've tried searching around and modifying MSBuild arguments, but to no avail.  This should be easy.  What am I missing?

These are the MSBuild arguments I have plugged in.  The last two (DeployOnBuild and CreatePackageOnPublish) don't seem to matter at all...not sure /t:Publish is making any difference either

```
/t:Publish
/p:TargetProfile=Cloud
/p:DeployOnBuild=false
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=false
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried removing all those MSBuild args?  The standard build workflow does not deploy to anything by default.  Also what build template are you using?

Comment: @gregpakes, don't I need the TargetProfile so it knows which service config file to use?  I'll remove the args, queue up another build, and see what happens.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: My understanding is that the profiles are for deployment only.  As you don't want to deploy, then I don't think you need it.

Comment: @gregpakes, nope, doesn't seem to make a difference when I remove all the MSBuild arguments.  Still gets deployed to Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use the correct build process template:

```
Right click the build definition -> Edit Build definition
Process tab
Up at the top there is a section for the Build Process Template
Show Details
Select "DefaultTemplate" from the dropdown
```

The options available in the process tab will be different than the AzureContinuousDeployment template I was using.  I didn't need any MSBuild arguments (though you might depending on how you named your service configs).

I had never noticed the template before.  Most people probably just assumed I was already using the default one!